# HandlebarsIntl intergration with webpack 3

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, handlebars.js, webpack-3

I wish to use [Handlebars Intl](https://formatjs.io/handlebars/) for my handlebar templates but it will throw an error 
'helpers.formatNumber is undefined' while using.

This is my web pack configuration

```
 {
        test: /\.tpl$/,
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views'),
        ],
        use: {
            loader: 'handlebars-loader',
            options: {
                minimize: true,
                assumeObjects: true,
                knownHelpers: ['formatNumber'],
                knownHelpersOnly: false,
                helperDirs: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/handlebar-helpers'),
                ],
                partialDirs: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views/partials')
                ],
                extensions: [
                    ".tpl"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my handlebar header.tpl

```
<li>{{formatNumber 25000}}</li>
```

I have already linked HandlebarsIntl with my Handlebars before it calls

HandlebarsIntl.registerWith(Handlebars); and i can see that registered helpers under Handlebars.helpers

Ref: 
https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader 
https://formatjs.io/handlebars/

please help me on this